# Scala Generic Parameter Type passed to Java Generic container

Tags: java, scala, generics, reflection

### **Question**: How I can pass Generic Type from Scala to Java so the next code in **JavaContainer** will not fail like this:

```sh
I'm instance of SomeClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at main.java.JavaContainer.print(JavaContainer.java:19)
    at main.scala.Main$.print(Main.scala:13)
    at main.scala.Main$.main(Main.scala:17)
    at main.scala.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

I have a given (and impossible to change Java class from external Jar) for this question we will call it: **JavaContainer**

```java
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
public /* You can remove the final marking, the problem is still there */ final class JavaContainer<T> {
  private Class<T> clazz;
  public JavaContainer(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public void print() {
    /* This one works */
    try {
      T unknown = clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* This one isn't */
    Class<T> persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    System.out.println(persistentClass.getName());
  }
}
```

I also have Java class which will be used as a Type Parameter: **SomeClass**

```java
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass() {
        System.out.println("I'm instance of SomeClass");
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a **Scala** class called **ScalaContainer**

```scala
import main.java.{JavaContainer, SomeClass}

class ScalaContainer[T]()(implicit m:Manifest[T]) {
  val clazz = m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
  val javaContainer : JavaContainer[T] = new JavaContainer[T](clazz)
}
```

And we also have our main method in **Main** object.

```scala
object Main {

  def print{
    val main = new ScalaContainer[SomeClass]()
    main.javaContainer.print()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    print
  }
}
```

Comment: `JavaContainer` seems inherently broken. The line calling `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` seems to assume that `T` will be resolved by an extending class (the way Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) works for example). But `JavaContainer` is marked as `final` so this is impossible.

Comment: reproduced without the final marking, so this is not the case.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm getting at. There needs to be a class that extends `JavaContainer<SomeConcreteType>` in order for `T` to be reifiable as `SomeConcreteType`. Whoever wrote `JavaContainer` was cargo-cult programming.

Comment: The thing is that I can pass anything I want when I'm in "Java world" however this is not the case when the type is coming from the "Scala world" or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Hrmmm.. I'm trying to picture your code and what it's doing. It's reminding me of using Hibernate with generic DAOs which I've done quite a bit so I would say you should look at http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html which would print SomeClass the way you set it up. There is also TypeTools here https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools

I *think* this should get you on the right path if I'm understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: You are right in your guessing this is related to DAO, although it's not hibernate but [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia). There is a [BasicDao](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/source/browse/trunk/morphia/src/main/java/com/google/code/morphia/dao/BasicDAO.java?r=1283) class which have this behavior I simplified this for the question.

Comment: ah i see. i would then definitely check out the TypeToken. You can use it directly or just look at how it's implemented. It's one of the ways I was able to get across the type erasure issues when making my daos.

Comment: The point is that I don't want to change Morphia code, I'm passing the generic parameter from the Scala class which I can change.
Even if I wrap this in Scala, I think this will happen anyway since the code failing is out of my reach.
I'll give it a try anyway.

Comment: Ah I see now. I didn't know that java piece was not under your control. Now this is bugging me... I can't make it work :(